# Android reflexion api instantiation exception

Tags: android, exception, reflection

I'm trying to instantiate through Class.newInstance() the following class:

```
public class TestCommand extends AccuBaseCommand {

LocationManager lm;

public TestCommand(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void command() 
{
    DisplayMetrics metric = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metric);
    Log.i("test",metric.density+"");        
}

@Override
public int getIcon() {
    return R.drawable.icon;
}
```

}

It is not abstract nor an interface it's a concrete class extension. Doing something wrong here? It throws InstatiationException.

Thanks in advance for any help,
JQCorreia

Comment: Seeing the class doesn't really help. Paste the logcat and the lines around the call to newInstance

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself on this one. Seeing the logcat output line saying something like "newinstance() error: () missing", and reading some more about reflection i understand the newInstance method requires a zero-args constructor to exist!

Addind this solved the issue!

Thanks again,
JQCorreia